# Guessing what user will input in textbox

Tags: c#

Is there a way in C# to guess what a user is going to input? For example, when you are typing in Visual Studio and you start with Fi, File comes up as an answer and prompts the user to hit enter to enter it. Is there a way to do this with textbox?

Comment: Have you tried searching for 'autocomplete'?

Comment: Which technology? asp.net, mvc, wpf, forms?

Comment: If you don't have any autocomplete textboxes, you can have a listbox with possible values, transfer what the user type to it and show the listbox result.

Comment: I had no idea textboxes had that AutoCompleteMode property.  That's awesome.

Answer (score 11):

It really depends on the complexity of your app but a straightforward way would be to set the [AutoCompleteMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletemode.aspx) property on the TextBox to the relevant [AutoCompleteMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.autocompletemode.aspx) enum. Example code from the MSDN link

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create the list to use as the custom source.  
    var source = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    source.AddRange(new string[]
                    {
                        "January",
                        "February",
                        "March",
                        "April",
                        "May",
                        "June",
                        "July",
                        "August",
                        "September",
                        "October",
                        "November",
                        "December"
                    });

    // Create and initialize the text box. 
    var textBox = new TextBox
                  {
                      AutoCompleteCustomSource = source,
                      AutoCompleteMode = 
                          AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend,
                      AutoCompleteSource =
                          AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource,
                      Location = new Point(20, 20),
                      Width = ClientRectangle.Width - 40,
                      Visible = true
                  };

    // Add the text box to the form.
    Controls.Add(textBox);
}
```